# Entity Framework - paging with group by skipping group

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following query:

```
var enumerable = repository.Elemtents.Where((s) =>
                DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.Timestamp) <= parameter.To.Date &&
                DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.Timestamp) >= parameter.From.Date)
            .OrderByDescending((s) => s.Timestamp)
            .GroupBy((s) => new {Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.Timestamp), s.Timestamp.Hour})
            .OrderByDescending((s) => s.Key.Date);
```

I now want to apply paging with Skip() and Take(). In my table (protocol entries) can be a large amount of data. So I coul do the following, but it would be a perfomance lack.

```
var result = enumerable
   .ToList()
   .SelectMany((x) => x)
   .Skip(0)
   .Take(2);
```

I want to apply Skip() and Take() on the query directly so that it will be done on the sql server. If I do the following, I get weird results:

```
var result = repository.Elemtents.Where((s) =>
                DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.Timestamp) <= parameter.To.Date &&
                DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.Timestamp) >= parameter.From.Date)
            .OrderByDescending((s) => s.Timestamp)
            .GroupBy((s) => new {Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.Timestamp), s.Timestamp.Hour})
            .OrderByDescending((s) => s.Key.Date)
            .Skip(0)
            .Take(2)
            .ToList();
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: What you mean _I get weird results_?

Comment: Are you trying to skip/take groups? I'm asking because your `ToList` sample is not doing that.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes I want to Skip/Take groups.

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki The Date values are like 4093\01\01

Comment: Your "direct" query works fine for me (`.OrderByDescending((s) => s.Timestamp)` is redundant, but it's ignored anyway). EF6.1.3, MSSQL.

Comment: I solved it using a plain SQL query.